# Jquery animate quiz

Tags: jquery

Hi guys I'd like to ask about to animate the jquery code, I just learn it and don't know how to solve it, i think it will be helpful for people here too because it's about animation,,

Write the code that on click to an element with id "social" animates from top 0, left 0, width 50px, to top 20, left 20, width 150px and after 2 seconds it goes back to its original position, include css and jquery code (you must use "this")?

Code

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#myImage').top('height','20px'); 
    $('#myImage').left({'height':20}); 
    $('#myImage').width(50); //assign 
    $('#myImage').height() //get })
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){

  $('animate').css('top','0px');
  $('animate').css({'left':0});
  $('animate').width(50); 
  $('animate').left(20);
  $('animate').left(150);
}) not sure if it's right because I just learn jquery today

Comment: You need a click handler for `#social`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(function() {
    var timer;
    $('#social').click(function() {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        $('#myImage').stop().animate({
            top : '20px',
            left : '20px',
            width : '150px'
        }, function() {
            timer = setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
                $(this).stop().animate(
                    {
                        top : '0',
                        left : '0',
                        width : '50px'
                    })
            }, this), 2000);
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: I need to use method "this" and that's the problem so far

Comment: where do you want to use `this`

Comment: I'm not sure how to use and to put "this", but regarding my teacher, I need to use method this to animate it

Comment: @Learner the updated sample uses `this` to revert the animation

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using `delay()` along with `animate()`. See my code, and the working example, below:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#social").animate({"top":20, "left": 20}).delay(20000).animate({"top":0, "left": 0});
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#social{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
}
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8Azz/2/)